# JSON Schema Dependency Between Properties in Separate Objects

Tags: json, jsonschema

Creating a schema for the following document:

```
{
    "name": "billy",
    "foo": {
        "this": "something"
    },
    "bar": {
        "that": "something"
    }
}
```

I want the schema to require `$.bar.that` if `$.foo.this` is present.

- Tried a dependency on this with a JSON pointer to that.
- Tried an if/then block, but I couldn't figure out how to say "`this` is present" in the if portion of the block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dependencies` only works with the current object, so it has to be done with `if`/`then`. You need to use `properties` to set `required` at every level.

```
{
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "foo": { "required": ["this"] }
    },
    "required": ["foo"]
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": {
      "bar": { "required": ["this"] }
    },
    "required": ["bar"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Shut the front door! That worked. The guidance on `dependencies` I get.  Using required in the `then` block makes sense. Using `required` in the `if` block? I'd have spent the remaining years of my life trying to figure that out to no avail. Do you know the thinking behind that syntax?

Comment: `if` is a schema like any other. If the `if` schema validates successfully, then the `then` schema must also validate. If the schema asserts that `/foo` and `/foo/this` are required, the instance can only be valid against that schema if `/foo/this` is present in the instance.

Comment: The schema bit makes sense. What isn't intuitive to me is the `required` bit. `required` (to me) means it must be present. However, present isn't synonymous with validated. Evidently, as a predicate in an if statement, that's the case.